# Mongoose fineOne not finding anything with a date

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am not able to find a record in MongoDB using findOne with a date.

My **Schema**:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  profileID:       String,
  notifications:   []
});

//I am storing the date variable as new Date();
```

My **data**:

```
{
"_id": "5938dc8db08803411af0cd05",
"profileID": "123",
"notifications": [
  {
    "read": false,
    "date": "2017-06-08 13:16:58"
  }
]
}
```

My **code**:

```
//I have taken the rest of the junk out as the problem is just with this part. By junk I mean routes and all for Node.js
console.log("1: " + req.body.date);
console.log("2: " + typeof(req.body.date));
console.log("3: " + req.body.id);

userModel.findOne({profileID: req.body.id, "notifications.date": new Date(req.body.date)},

  function(err, data) {
    if (err){
      console.log("4: " + err);
    } else {
      console.log("5: " + data);
    }
});
```

The console.log's results:

```
1: 2017-06-08 13:16:58
2: string
3: 123
5: null
```

What am I doing wrong? I have tried all sorts of approaches with the date and yet it's not working.

This is certainly an issue with the date but how will I get it to work?

My stack: MongoDB v: 3.1.5, Mongoose: 4.4.10

Thanks in advance

Comment: `notifications:   []` suggests that your dates are actually "strings". You probably should have a declared a schema for the embedded documents to make sure these were cast as dates. But right now your dates are most certainly strings.

Comment: Also `profileID: req.body.date` isn't right. You want `"123"` to match the document and that should be coming in as a separate parameter. Despite your logging claims `req.body.date` is certainly not **both** `"2017-06-08 13:16:58"` and `"123"`

Comment: Typo, thanks for pointing it out. And for your first comment, can you guide me on where do I start? Are you saying it should've been something like:

notifications: [read: Boolean, date: Date]

Comment: You can define a "Schema" for the array content like `notifications: [NotificationSchema]`. And the schema definition is just the same as for any mongoose schema. You just only use it like that rather than linking to a model. All in the documentation. It's good to read the documentation.

Comment: Sorry man, I don't mean to push you guys too much. I will take your approach and focus on the Schema documentation (I didn't have an idea the problem could be there). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of defining `notifications` in that manner, you need to define it as an array of objects specifying the types of its contents. Your new schema should be:

```js
var userSchema = new Schema({
  profileId: String,
  notifications: [{
    read: Boolean,
    date: Date
  }]    
});
```

This should solve your problem and return a date.

Comment: This worked for me. In fact, when I did this, it gave me a _id value and to be honest, that's more for me than the date value. So I went with that in the end but anyhow, for the sake of this question, your answer is correct. Cheers!

Comment: Glad I could be of help mate! :)